# Jquery add mouseup and mousedown event on several images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a mouseup, mousedown, hover event on several different images - the only problem is that the event only occurs on the first image, 
tried using the each() function does not seem to be working.
Any suggestions on how I can do this?

```
    $(function() {

var filename = $('.imgover').attr('alt');

$('.rolloverimg').each(function(){
   $('#'+ filename).mouseup(function(){
      $(this).children("img").attr('src', 'content/images/buttons/'+ filename + '_up.png' );
    }).mousedown(function(){
      $(this).children("img").attr('src','content/images/buttons/' + filename + '_down.png');
    });

    $('#'+ filename).hover(
      function () {
        $(this).children("img").attr('src', 'content/images/buttons/'+ filename + '_hover.png');
      },
      function () {
        $(this).children("img").attr('src', 'content/images/buttons/' + filename + '_up.png');
      }
    );
});

});

<div class="hdr-btns rolloverimg">
      <a href="#"><img src="content/images/buttons/play_up.png" alt="play" id="play"  class="imgover" /></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="content/images/buttons/register_up.png" alt="register" id="register"  class="imgover" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no need to implement a loop** in order to add events to multiple elements using jQuery. You can simply apply the events to a selector that selects all the elements that you need.

For example, the following code adds MouseUp and MouseDown events to all the img tags inside an element that has the `rolloverimg` class:

```
$('.rolloverimg img').mouseup(function () {
    alert('up')
}).mousedown(function () {
    alert('down');
});
```

And if you want to quick test it, here is the full working example that was created starting from your source code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.rolloverimg img').mouseup(function () {
            alert('up')
        }).mousedown(function () {
            alert('down');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hdr-btns rolloverimg">
        <a href="#"><img src="content/images/buttons/play_up.png" alt="play" id="play" class="imgover" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="content/images/buttons/register_up.png" alt="register" id="register" class="imgover" /></a>
        <input type="button" value="text" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Additional info update**
If you do not want to select all the img tags from the div, but rather just the ones that have the `imgover` class applied to them, you can use the following selector:

```
$(function () {
    $('.rolloverimg img.imgover').mouseup(function () {
        alert('up')
    }).mousedown(function () {
        alert('down');
    });
});
```

**Additional info update2**
You can access the currently selected element using `$(this)`. For example:

```
$('.rolloverimg img.imgover').mouseup(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id') + '_up')
}).mousedown(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id') + '_down');
});
```

Please let me know if the above helps or if you need more specific help.

Comment: Yes but its need to be dynamic as not all images will have the same name.

Comment: @NiseNise, not sure what you mean. I am not selecting by name, but rather by "tag name". In this case, images are represented using img tags and I am selecting all the **img** tags inside the element with the rolloverimg class applied to it (the container div in this case).

Comment: Yes, but I need it know the id of that image as using your method all it does is replace the second image with the first on mouseup and mousedown.

Comment: @NiseNise, I think I understand what you need. I will update my answer.

Comment: Mmm that still does not work... 
var filename = $('.imgover').attr('src');
    $('.rolloverimg img.imgover').mouseup(function () {
        alert('up: '+ filename)
    }).mousedown(function () {
        alert('down:'+ filename);
    });

Answer (score 1):

put the code:

var filename = $('.imgover').attr('alt');

inside the each function.

Comment: Yes. It is setting the filename before you are doing the each loop so using the first one it finds throughout your loop. By putting it inside the function you are changing the filename to the current alt attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [simple way to do it](http://www.jsfiddle.net/gMvJH/):

```
$('.rolloverimg').mouseover(function() {
    $('img', this).each(function () {
        $(this).attr('alt', $(this).attr('id') + '_over');
    })
}).mouseout(function() {
  $('img', this).each(function () {
        $(this).attr('alt', $(this).attr('id') + '_out');
    })
});
```

Of course, juste replace the attr('alt', 'in') to do what you need (set the src attribute), it is just a simple way to show the logic of selecting the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You may just use $('.rolloverimg img').mouseup() etc.

```
$('.rolloverimg img').mouseup(function(){
      $(this).children("img").attr('src', 'content/images/buttons/'+ filename + '_up.png' );
    }).mousedown(function(){
      $(this).children("img").attr('src','content/images/buttons/' + filename + '_down.png');
    });

$('.rolloverimg img').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).children("img").attr('src', 'content/images/buttons/'+ filename + '_hover.png');
      },
      function () {
        $(this).children("img").attr('src', 'content/images/buttons/' + filename + '_up.png');
      }
    );
```